# Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-facebook4'

Tags: facebook, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, facebook-login

I was tried to install cordova plugin facebook but it's can't install this plugin

[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gXFa.jpg)

Comment: Please don't use pictures. Links can later become broken and search engines cannot index your question well. Please edit your question and copy-paste the error from your console.

Comment: Would be nicer to provide some context information such as what is your project, what are the versions of each software tools and components used etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It fails because your project is in a path that contains *non-ascii* (cyrilic?) characters.

I'm talking about the

```
E:\<non-ascii foldername>\Turtle\platforms\android\...
```

You could rename that folder or move the contents elsewhere and see if it works.

WARNING: renaming or moving the folder may probably break many installations that depend on that, environment variables, etc.

**I strongly advise that you uninstall any software development programs you installed on `E:\` and *reinstall it* somewhere else** (any path that doesn't have weird foldernames).